# Javascript, alert if a value on $(reviewForm).serialize() is blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm submitting a form with JS and I want to cancel the submit if any field is blank.

I'm getting all values with: `$(reviewForm).serialize()`

which returns something like:

```
id=2&text=aaaa&rating=2&gender=
```

How can I show an alert if any value in the form is blank?

Comment: $(reviewForm) looks like jQuery. You using plain JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var serialized = $(reviewForm).serialize();
>
> ```
> if(serialized.indexOf('=&') > -1 || serialized.substr(serialized.length - 1) == '='){
>    //you've got empty values
> }
> ```

using jQuery, you can test it before serializing:

```
$(reviewForm).find('input').each(function(idx, elem){
   if($(elem).val().length == 0){
       //this field is empty
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before submitting the form you can do something like this.

```
if($(reviewForm).find('input, select, textarea').filter(function(){
      return $(this).val() == '';
   }).length > 0){
      alert('Enter all the values');
}
else{
    //Submit the form here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check for empty fields, return array of the field names, and alert how many fields are empty. check the fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/Pwngn/

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var s = $(this).serialize();
    var empty = $.grep(s.split('&'), function(field){
        //get empty fields
        return field.split('=')[1] === '';
    }).map(function(arr){
        //return field name of empty field
        return arr.split('=')[0];
    });
    alert(empty.length + ' empty fields');
    return !empty.length;
});
```